# Is it possible to get access to RAW servlet request from servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, request

This is probably silly question but i want to be sure.

When you have simple html form like this:

```
  <form action='/requestlogger' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='field1' value='fo' />
    <input type='hidden' name='field2' value='bar'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='field3' value='baz'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
  </form>
```

and make submit then browser generates request like this:

```
POST http://localhost:9090/requestlogger HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Referer: http://localhost:9090/requestlogger/requestlogger.jsp
Accept-Language: pl-PL
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; CMDTDF; BRI/1; BRI/2; .NET4.0C)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:9090
Content-Length: 31
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=69A1DD26A835FDBD8CAEA8BB3BEBF36B

field1=fo&field2=bar&field3=baz
```

I was curious if i can catch this raw data from servlet so i wrote test method:

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    try {
        Writer out = resp.getWriter();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(req.getReader());
        String read = br.readLine();
        while(read != null) {
            out.write(read);
            read = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But i only got:

```
field1=fo&field2=bar&field3=baz
```

When i think about this, this is exactly what i suppose to get because webserver (tomcat) handle complex stuff and i get ready to use HttpServletRequest and all header data is available by API (req.getContentLength(), req.getCookies(), req.getHeaderNames() etc.)

So i think that you cant get acces to "full" RAW request data from servlet? Or i am missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You would probably have to rebuild it using the methods for all the different pieces.

Comment: developerwjk I am sorry but i dont understand what you mean

Comment: I mean probably you would have to use getMethod(), getHeaderNames(), getRequestURL(), etc. to rebuild the raw request text, because it doesn't look like there's any other way.

Comment: That's exactly what I suspect, because WebServer parse this RAW request and servlet gets ready to use HttpServletRequest object, but i was curious if there is a copy of original request available. I gues there is no reason for such functionality to exist.